# How to fix assignment to expression with array type error in sorting structure c

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, structure

How can I fix the error "assignment to expression with array type" when I try to compare the pointer that point to the structure. I want to sort the user data based on the selected column (e.g. activity) by using a condition to ask users to choose they want to sort the user data based on the given choice. Then after that, I want to run the program then the problems appear.

Here is my structure of my codes:

```
struct fitnessTracking {
    char activity[50], unit[50];
    int calories;
    float total, weight, height, bmi;
};
struct recordDate {
    int dd, mm, yyyy;
    int duration;
};
struct user {
    char username[50];
    struct fitnessTracking tracker;
    struct recordDate record;
};

struct Number {
    struct Number *ptrnext;
    struct user member;
};

struct Number *newptr, *currentptr;
```

Here is my activity sort function:

```
void activitySort(struct Number *head){
    struct Number *temp = NULL; struct Number *ptr=NULL;
    currentptr = head;

    if(head == NULL)
        return;

    while(currentptr != NULL){ //while current pointer not null
        ptr = currentptr->ptrnext;
        while(ptr != NULL){
            if(currentptr->member.tracker.activity > ptr->member.tracker.activity){
                temp = currentptr->member.tracker.activity;
                currentptr->member.tracker.activity = ptr->member.tracker.activity;
                ptr->member.tracker.activity = temp;
            }ptr = ptr->ptrnext;
        }currentptr=currentptr->ptrnext;
    }
}
```

The error shows on these 2 lines with the error code `error: assignment to expression with array type`

```
currentptr->member.tracker.activity = ptr->member.tracker.activity;
ptr->member.tracker.activity = temp;
```

How can I fix them?

Comment: Arrays fo not have the assignment operator. It seems you are trying to assign arrays. What is the type of activity?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow how can I change it?

Comment: You need at first provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: In particular provide the definition of the structs you are using.

Comment: There's more than one problem here. `if(currentptr->member.tracker.activity > ptr->member.tracker.activity)` is totally wrong even though the compiler will probably not see the error. What does this comparison mean?  In addition you are trying to swap only `activity` while leaving all the other `struct` members alone. This doesn't look like a meaningful sorting.